# Unique() doesn't remove duplicates in two instances of seq()

Tags: r, unique, sequence

In the R I have two vectors created by `seq()`. One vector is a subset of the other. After concatenation, `unique()` returns what look like duplicate values: `0.6, 0.7, 0.9`

```
 set.seed(27)
 x <- seq(from = 0.1, to = 1.0, by = 0.1)
 y <- seq(from = 0.2, to = 1.0, by = 0.1)
 unique(c(x, y))
 # 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0 0.6 0.7 0.9
```

I confirmed this with `setdiff()`

```
setdiff(x, y)
# 0.1 0.6 0.7 0.9

setdiff(y, x)
# 0.6 0.7 0.9
```

Why does R consider `0.6, 0.7, 0.9` to be different values in the two vectors?

Comment: Look at `x[9]-y[8]` and you'll see that this is our old friend binary representation of decimal numbers... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558#9508558. You could get round it by using `round()`.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Our "old friend" indeed!